# Iterate through all children and children children of an object

Tags: javascript, object, parent-child

I have an object with children objects, and even great grandchildren objects.

I am currently using

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Which produces, for example:

- created_at: 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
- id: string
- data: [object Object]
- items: [object Object],[object Object]

How do I iterate through any number of child objects to return something similar to

- created_at: 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
- id: string
- data: [object Object]
- data: 1 of 1 {contents}
- items: 1 of 2 {contents}
- items: 2 of 2 {contents}

The "1 of 2" isn't needed, but demonstrates my output goal.

Comment: check the type of value and if it is an object call the same function recursively

Comment: It may require writing a set of mutually-recursive functions: `printObjects()`, `printData()`, `printItems()` and etc. The main function will print the ID and call `printData(curr.data)` for example. Each one of these functions may call one of the other functions if there's a need. From the example you posted it's not clear which objects can be under each fields, but the structure looks recursive. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a situation where [*recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is useful. For example:

```
function visitDescendants(obj, callback) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse
            visitDescendants(value, callback);
        } else {
            callback(key, value);
        }
    }    
}
```

Live example:

```js
function visitDescendants(obj, callback) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse
            visitDescendants(value, callback);
        } else {
            callback(key, value);
        }
    }    
}

const obj = {
    a: 1,
    message: "hi",
    b: {
        nestedMessage: "there",
        c: {
            furtherNestedMessage: "folks!"
        },
    },
};

visitDescendants(obj, (key, value) => {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
});
```